# Should your Nameservers be under a Different Domain

Tags: domains, dns, nameserver

I notice that, with most of the web hosts I use, they provide nameserver addresses under their main domain (or a related domain).

For example **Mediatemple** provides name servers which are:

1. `ns1.mediatemple.net`
2. `ns2.mediatemple.net`

So when I setup a website on their servers, under a domain like `myserver.com` the nameservers are not under that domain.

When I was setting up with a new host for another site, they setup nameservers under the domain of the site I was setting up. So, the website I was installing was `myserver.com`, they setup nameservers as `ns1.myserver.com` and `ns2.myserver.com`.

**Is this best practice? Should the nameservers be associated with a different domain?**

(*My thoughts are that they should, otherwise you need to access the DNS records for `myserver.com` in order to find out where the servers which house the DNS records you just accessed are.... Sounds a bit chicken & egg to me.*)
Any advice or observations greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to set up nameservers for a brand new domain with names under that domain; so, `example.com` *could* (if it wasn't a reserved domain) have nameservers of `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com`. Most registrars will prompt for the IP addresses to associate with the records at the time, to avoid the chicken/egg scenario.

For situations where you do not control your nameservers (i.e. you're using a hosting business in between), I wouldn't recommend registering their servers under your name (after all, they could choose to move to different IP ranges, and all of a sudden your NS records are pointing at the wrong place)